# How to Add List Item to Unordered List in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a web app (todo list) that contains a form and a list. Every time the user submits the form, the item submitted will be added to the list as li. I know how to add a list item to ul. My problem is that I want to be able to format the newly added li as the previous one. I'm doing the project using bootstrap, which has its own predefined classes. So I'd like to add new li with those classes. Here's the web app online http://pctechtips.org/apps/todo/
this is how a single li will look like and so when new li's are added I would like to know how can I keep the same format

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
Morbi leo risus
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</li>
```

```js
//javascript file


//variables
//todoList array to hold (title, description) for every todo tiem
var todoList = [{
    title: "Buy Groceries",
    desc: "go to win-dixie and buy bread, ham, and cheese"
  },
  {
    title: "Pay Car Insurance",
    desc: "call State Farm and pay year insureance"
  },
  {
    title: "Do this",
    desc: "this is another todo item description"
  }
]

/*
 * Script main body
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide form when doc loads first time
  $("#submit-form").hide();

  //listener for show hide form functionality
  $("#add-todo").click(function() {
    toggleForm();
    return false; //return false to prevent page reload
  });

  //listener for add new item form (submit button)
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    console.log("submit item");
    addToList();
  });
});

//functionality for show / hide form
function toggleForm() {
  if ($("#submit-form").is(":hidden")) {
    console.log("form exapnded");
    $("#submit-form").show("slow");
    $("#form-icon").removeClass("fa-plus-square-o");
    $("#form-icon").addClass("fa-minus-square-o");
  } else {
    console.log("form hidden");
    $("#submit-form").hide("slow");
    $("#form-icon").removeClass("fa-minus-square-o");
    $("#form-icon").addClass("fa-plus-square-o");
  }
}

//add new item to todo list items
function addToList() {
  //getting data from input fields
  var todoTitle = $("#todo-title").val();
  var todoDesc = $("#todo-desc").val();
  //checking user input
  if (todoTitle == null || todoDesc == null) {
    alert("fill in all fields!");
  } else {
    console.log(todoTitle + "\n" + todoDesc);
    //adding new li to ul   
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todoTitle));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    // li.innerHtml = "<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">"+todoTitle+"<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>"

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TodoList App</title>
  <!-- bootstrap, fontawsome cdn -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- local stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <!-- jquery cdn -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- local javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/todo.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-drak bg-dark mb-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack" aria-hidden="true"></i> Todo<strong>List</strong></a>
  </nav>
  <!-- /navbar -->
  <!-- todoList -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="add-item text-white text-center col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 mb-4">
      <a id="add-todo" class="new-todo text-white text-center" href=""><i id="form-icon" class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Enter new todo item</a>
      <div id="submit-form" class="form-hide text-center col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
        <form class="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-title" placeholder="Todo Title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="todo-desc" placeholder="Todo Description">
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg col-12">Submit Todo</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- horizontal line -->
      <hr>
      <!-- list items -->
      <h1 class="heading-4">Todo List Items</h1>
      <ul id="list" class="list-group mt-4 pb-4">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Pay Car Insurance
          <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Dapibus ac facilisis in
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          Morbi leo risus
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Jquery. So you can use it to add classes and append child elements.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("list");
var li = document.createElement("li");

$(li).addClass("list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center");
$(li).append(document.createTextNode(todoTitle));
$(li).append(($('<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>')));
```

Only thing I have added is the addClass() method and append() method to add the required classes and append the trash icon.

Check the fiddle here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/vL6vym69/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: is it better do this with jquery or javascript... it's obvious that jquery makes it incredibly easy

Comment: It depends on what you do with them. Since you have already included jquery, I don't see any valid point in not using it. For a simple append task like this, it will not have any considerable overhead because jquery uses the same vanilla js under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Before you append the new `li` you can do this to match the classes:

```
$previous = $(ul.children[ul.children.length-1]);
$(li).attr('class', $previous.attr('class'));
```

And copy the trash can:

```
$('i', $previous).clone().appendTo(li);
```

This needs to be performed in `addToList()` right before `.appendChild(li)`